# Open a file in git bash through atom in Windows 7

Tags: git, path, atom-editor

I have recently started learning git. The problem is that when I open a file in git bash using atom ('''atom Read_python.txt'''), even if the file is present in current working directory it opens it in C:\Users\Ritik Singh\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.51.0\Read_python.txt

I have installed atom through the executable file.
Added "**C:\Users\Ritik Singh\AppData\Local\atom;C:\Users\Ritik Singh\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Ritik Singh\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.51.0**" in path variable.(Windows 7 format)

How to make it open the file in current working directory?

Comment: It is enough to register as path just this one "C:\Users\Ritik Singh\AppData\Local\atom\bin". Try to remove others. I've tested on my machine, everything works like a charm.

Comment: It worked..!! @kosist thanks a lot. Wasted hours searching for the solution but couldn't find one.